# Relation between uniform continuity and holder condition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, holder-spaces

> Let $\;f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^m\;$ and $\;g:\mathbb R^m
>  \rightarrow \mathbb R\;$. Assume $\;g\;$ is uniform continuous in $\;\{ \vert f \vert \le M\;\}\;$, i.e.$\;\forall \varepsilon
>  \gt 0\;$ $\exists \;δ\gt 0\;$  :
>
> $\;\vert g(f_1)-g(f_2) \vert \le \varepsilon\;$,  $\; \vert f_1-f_2
>  \vert \le δ\;$ for $f_1,f_2 \in \{ \vert f \vert \le M\;\}\;(1)$ ($\;M\;$
>   some positive constant).
>
> If in addition, each $\;f\in \{ \vert f \vert \le M\;\}\;$ satisfies a Holder condition:
>
> $\; \vert f(x_1)-f(x_2) \vert \le L {\vert x_1 -x_2 \vert}^{\frac
>  {1}{2}}\;(2)$ for some $\;L\gt 0\;$

then **I wonder if it is possible somehow to claim
$\;\vert g(f(x_1))-g(f(x_2)) \vert \le \varepsilon\;$ for $\; L {\vert x_1 -x_2 \vert}^{\frac {1}{2}}\le δ\;$.....?**

***EDIT:*** Consider the norm mentioned as the Euclidean norm in $\;\mathbb R^m\;$

To be more specific, I'm interested in finding **the relation between $\;(1)\;$ and $\;(2)\;$** in order to prove the above claim. I have been trying a lot before I ask here but the fact that in condition $\;(1)\;$ I have the same variable with different functions while in condition $\;(2)\;$ I have the same function with different variables , confuses me a lot.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As written, the condition after "i.e." makes no sense.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli What do you mean?

Comment: The notation is inconsistent with what the symbols are defined to be.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Is it better now..?

Comment: For all $\varepsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that [[$\lvert g(f_1)-g(f_2)\rvert<\varepsilon$ and some unspecified norm of $f_1-f_2$ is $<\delta$] whenever the aforementioned norm applied to $f_1$ and $f_2$ is $\le M$].